# iOS: Push notification not showing dictionary info in iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, apple-push-notifications, ios10

I am working on push notification in XCode 8 Beta, iOS 10 Version. I have got push notification received on device. When I clicked on notification, it fired delegate of UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, app is opened, but it didn't show any response in userinfo. Do I need to change parameter for sending push in iOS 10 on server side. Below is my code.

```
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];

    UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    center.delegate = self;
    [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionBadge | UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert) completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"request authorization succeeded!");
        }
    }];


- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler {

    NSLog(@"Notification is triggered");
    completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert);
}

- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler {

    NSLog(@"Tapped in notification");
    NSLog(@"%@",response.notification);
    NSString *actionIdentifier = response.actionIdentifier;

    if ([actionIdentifier isEqualToString:@"com.apple.UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier"] ||
        [actionIdentifier isEqualToString:@"com.apple.UNNotificationDismissActionIdentifier"]) {
        return;
    }
}
```

In iOS 9,

```
aps =     {
    alert = "Multi extra param push.";
    badge = 0;
    sound = default;
};
t = I;
url = "http://www.google.com";
```

and in iOS 10

```
alert = "Multi extra param push.";
badge = 0;
sound = default;
```

Comment: why are you using beta iOS version ?

Comment: try this  NSLog(@"%@",[response.notification.request.content.userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"]);

Comment: In iOS 9     aps =     {
        alert = "Multi extra param push.";
        badge = 0;
        sound = default;
    };
    t = I;
    url = "http://www.google.com";
In iOS 10     alert = "Multi extra param push.";
    badge = 0;
    sound = default;

Comment: I am not getting url and t value in iOS 10, is there any way to retrieve or do I need to change any thing.

Comment: I got the solution how to do, thanks for all the help

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
       willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler {
    NSLog(@"%@", notification.request.content.userInfo);
}

- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
         withCompletionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler {
    NSLog(@"%@", response.notification.request.content.userInfo);
}
```